# Parse values in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, coffeescript

I have a 5x5, table in HTML, that is, each tr has 5 td's, and each td has one input field, which i want to parse for value, also each td has data attributes for data-row and data-column. this is what i have come up with, but it's buggy, how do i do it?

```
tds = $('td')
marker = 0
thisSet = []
table = []

for td in tds
 thisRow = parseInt($(td).attr('data-row'))

 if marker == thisRow
  rc = "#{$(td).attr('data-row')}-#{$(td).attr('data-column')}"
  thisSet.push ({data: rc})
  console.log "marker:#{marker}, thisRow:#{thisRow}"
else
  rc = "#{$(td).attr('data-row')}-#{$(td).attr('data-column')}"
  thisSet.push ({data: rc})
  marker = thisRow 
  console.log "marker:#{marker}, thisRow:#{thisRow}"
  table.push thisSet
  thisSet = []

console.log table
console.log _.flatten(table).length
```

UPDATE: ok, worked a little more on it, now i have 4 rows parsed, not the 5th row, theres something missing, but 4 rows parse fine.

```
tds = $('td')
currentRow = 0
thisSet = []
table = []
for td in tds
  thisRow = parseInt($(td).attr('data-row'))
  rc = "#{$(td).attr('data-row')}-#{$(td).attr('data-column')}"

 if currentRow != thisRow
  table.push thisSet
  thisSet = []
  thisSet.push ({data: rc})
  currentRow = thisRow 
else
  thisSet.push ({data: rc})

console.log table
console.log _.flatten(table).length
```

Comment: For one thing, you're lacking the {} in your for...in loop and also your if() {} else {} logic.

Comment: @joshstrike note the `coffeescript` tag

Comment: @koala_dev ...Ahh. sorry. Missed that

Comment: So you want to end up with a multi-dimensional array corresponding to the table, with the contents of each element simply being `"[row]-[column]"`?

Comment: yes micha! something like this:  [[Object { data="0-0"}, Object { data="0-1"}, Object { data="0-2"}, 2 more...], [Object { data="1-0"}, Object { data="1-1"}, Object { data="1-2"}, 2 more...], [Object { data="2-0"}, Object { data="2-1"}, Object { data="2-2"}, 2 more...], [Object { data="3-0"}, Object { data="3-1"}, Object { data="3-2"}, 2 more...]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do it like this:

```
table = []
table.push([]) for num in [0...5]

tds = $('td')

for td in tds
  row = parseInt(td.attr(data-row))
  col = parseInt(td.attr(data-column))

  table[row][col] = { data: "#{row}-#{col}" }

console.log table
```